# Тестирование Android приложения как бета версию

Tags: android, google-play

Добрый день!

Тестирую систему внутренних платежей для приложения.
Опубликовал приложение как бета версию, организовал закрытое тестирование. Ввел свой почтовый ящик (он же закреплет за телефоном). Получил ссылку, открываю по ссылке приложени (при этом удалил ту версию с телефона, которая была установлена). Нажимаю - установить, а он мне пишет - "Другой пользователь уже установил несовместимую версию этого приложения".

Какой другой пользователь? Почему оно не совместимо?! Ничего не понятно. 
Если скачиваю на прямую подписанную apk и пытаюсь установить, то пишет - "Установка не удалась".
Если запускаю программу через Android Studio то все ок. работает. Но платежи не проходят.

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалите через [adb uninstall](https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/install-and-uninstall-applications-using-adb). Так же если писали тесты для приложения, то удалите и их с телефона.

Answer (score 0):

На устройстве может быть не один пользователь. Быстрый доступ к смене пользователей можно получить в notification bar. Сменить пользователя и удалить нужное приложение.